# (Jest) test.each() not working with async body?

Tags: async-await, jestjs

(I'm asking here before reporting as a bug, as stated in the repo.)

The `test.each()` method seems to be giving me wrong results when used with an async body.

---

#### Example

This correctly succeeds:

```js
async function getVal(n) {
  return n === 1 ? "one" : "two";
}

test.each([
  [1, "one"],
  [2, "two"]
])("getVal()", async function (n, expected) {
  const val = await getVal(n);

  expect(val).toEqual(expected);
});
```

If I then change the first expected value, the test fails (so it still works).

```js
test.each([
  [1, "SOME VALUE"],
  [2, "two"]
])("getVal()", async function (n, expected) {
  const val = await getVal(n);

  expect(val).toEqual(expected);
});
```

But if I change the second expected value, the test wrongly says that it's succeeding (as if it's not really checking the second iteration at all).

```js
test.each([
  [1, "one"],
  [2, "SOME VALUE"]
])("getVal()", async function (n, expected) {
  const val = await getVal(n);

  expect(val).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the Test Explorer extension I was using ([Jest Test Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kavod-io.vscode-jest-test-adapter)).

It's reporting a `test.each()` as succeeding if its first case succeeds (regardless of the other cases).

[image]